# In C, can I keep strings as char* and then use pointers to point to other strings?

Tags: c, pointers, char

If I create a string like

```
char string[6] = "hello";
char* ptr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(string));
strcpy(ptr, string);
```

and then I do this:

```
char* ptr2 = ptr;
```

will it work?

In general, if I have a char* pointer to a string, can I make other pointers point to that string and the initial pointer point to another string?

[EDIT]

Thanks for your feedback but I'm a little confused. I'll try to take things from the beginning.

1. I have my main in which I do a scanf to read a string which is of not fixed size but has a MAX length. I read it like this `char* input; scanf("%as", &input);`. I think the 'a' flag allocates automatically the required memory to fit the string.
2. Then I have to call a function `foo(char* s)` which takes the string as input.
3. Inside that function, I have to store the string in memory. I have two options: either use the parameter or make a new malloc and strcpy and use the new string. Which of the two is correct? I just need to store the memory location of the string and refer to it later.
4. If I use the parameter and store the memory location of it somewhere, is this safe or because the pointer to a string is constant will it cause any problems? Will making another string with malloc solve anything or is it the same thing?

Until now I have tried several combinations but I couldn't achieve what I wanted. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As long as you've allocated space for all your actual strings (whether via malloc or declaring char arrays), what you've suggested should work for your pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char[6] string = "hello";
```

won't work at all. You mean `char string[] = "hello";`

And yes, you can have pointers *alias* each other, i.e. point to the same buffer. Be careful that you don't `free` both of them though, or use any of the aliasing pointers after one of them has been `free`'d.

This is, in fact, very useful. Consider the typical implementation of `strcpy`, which must return its first argument:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, char const *src)
{
    char *p = dest;  // aliasing pointers
    while (*src != '\0')
        *p++ = *src++;
    return dest;
}
```

And yes, after `char *p2 = p1`, you can point `p1` at another buffer, but that's mainly useful in tricky pointer algorithms. Again, be careful with memory allocation.

Comment: The question's been edited to be valid C, but +1 for pointer aliasing.

Comment: @nmichaels: I thought it would be an appropriate term to drop, given the subtleties surrounding the (strict/`restrict`) aliasing rules.

Comment: Are you sure that I can point p1 at another buffer later? Isn't p1 supposed to be a constant pointer?

Comment: @user: if `p1` is supposed to be a constant pointer, you can mark it such with `char *const p1`. If it isn't marked `const`, it can be reset as far as the compiler is concerned.